# Pandas: which “function names” can be used? (how are they looked up?)

Tags: pandas

When using pandas you can in certain cases pass names of functions as strings instead of actual references to those functions. For example: `df.transform('round')`.

In the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) they call these strings "function names".

I discovered that the lookup mechanism here doesn't look at the current namespace:

```py
import pandas as pd

sales = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "price": [23.12, 22.34, 12.56, 27.78, 11.9],
})

display(sales)

def new_price(price):
    return price * 1.1


display(sales.transform('round')) # Works
display(sales.transform(new_price)) # Works
display(sales.transform('new_price')) # Does not work
```

My question: is there a list of these function names that you can use in cases like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the relevant code from the pandas source:

```py
class Apply(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    ...

    def _try_aggregate_string_function(self, obj, arg: str, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        if arg is a string, then try to operate on it:
        - try to find a function (or attribute) on ourselves
        - try to find a numpy function
        - raise
        """
        assert isinstance(arg, str)

        f = getattr(obj, arg, None)
        if f is not None:
            if callable(f):
                return f(*args, **kwargs)

            # people may try to aggregate on a non-callable attribute
            # but don't let them think they can pass args to it
            assert len(args) == 0
            assert len([kwarg for kwarg in kwargs if kwarg not in ["axis"]]) == 0
            return f

        f = getattr(np, arg, None)
        if f is not None and hasattr(obj, "__array__"):
            # in particular exclude Window
            return f(obj, *args, **kwargs)

        raise AttributeError(
            f"'{arg}' is not a valid function for '{type(obj).__name__}' object"
        )
```

It basically searches for a method of self with that name or for a numpy method.